# What is the difference between ServletRequest's getRemoteHost() and getServerName()

Tags: java, servlets

The javadoc is a bit confusing to me, and in my local tests it seems like they both return the same thing.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

[**`getRemoteHost`**](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost%28%29) returns the name of the *client* that sent the request, while [**`getServerName`**](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29) returns the name of the *server* that received the request.

It might be the same results in your local tests if you are using two machines on the network, one as a client and one for the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where this confusion is coming from, the javadoc is very explicit:

[`getRemoteHost()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost()):

> Returns the fully qualified **name of
>   the client** or the last proxy that
>   sent the request.

[`getServerName()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName()):

> Returns the host **name of the server**
>   to which the request was sent.

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same thing, because you runs both the client and server at the **same machine**.